# Android - How to sent Data to Arduino through Headphone Jack

Tags: android, arduino, headset

How to send and receive the data to / from arduino through headphone jack in android. Is there any sample to start the code for android. As i come across various sites, they were told like Digital data from arduino has to be send as audio signal to smartphone and the same has to demodulated at smartphone and vice-versa but i didn't get better sample to start this process, so can any one suggest a sample to start.

I have checked this too, [headphone data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248649/sending-data-through-headphone-jack-in-android-phones) but not get clear

Comment: I think you're going to need 2 optocouplers to do that. And implement a communication protocol to encode/decode signals... wouldn't it be easier to buy a cheap HC05 module from China (5 USD on eBay)??

Comment: HCO5 is a Bluetooth module right, but i m gonna communicated through 3.5 mm jack only !!

Comment: Yes. Wouldn't BlueTooth be a BETTER CHOICE? Greater distance covered (10 mt without problems), known communication protocols (after all is always serial), easy to assemble, no fear to fry some devices (at best your Arduino, at worst your phone)...

Comment: @BobMalooga Optocoupler are used for process light signal data so these are irrelevant to my objective.

Comment: I have tried with bluetooth module specified above and it working fine for me, but the objective idea is send data through the headphone jack :-(

Comment: But the length of tha cable might be an issue. And you must implement your own communication protocol. Still asking myself W-H-Y using a headphone jack? Is it worth the effort?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52101/discussion-between-jerith-and-bob-malooga)