# Android , send out a signal to headset jack

Tags: android

I want to send out some customized signals to headset jack output ( 3.5 mm ) instead of music. Is there any high level library (or protocol) for this purpose?

If not , what native android library i must use ?

Regards ...

Comment: I thing your question is answered in another thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/7956506/812598

Comment: @GoRoS :Thank you ! I saw that before.It couldnt help me ...