# Get data from the phone jack audio line-in instead of phone microphone

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I am searching the answer from google and android website.

Because the iPhone can do that. But I can't find the Android has the API to do.

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,19648.0.html

Because the microphone pin and GND pin maybe change in the different android phone. 
So, I try to use the line-in (right) to get the data.

I checked the Hijack project, it used the microphone pin to get data, and used iPhone.

Does android phone can do the same function?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7956506/1239966

Comment: Hi, Shivam, Thank you for the information.
But that can't answer me for the question. 
I think that iPhone can provide the function, how about the android phone???

Comment: OK. I found the solution. 
It is impossible to do that in android phone. Because the HW (codec) is not support the function.
Thank you.

Comment: It can very much be done in android phones. You can use the headphone jack to get data. Check out the square android app.